# How to update Update X509 certificates for On-Premise Service Fabric cluster

Tags: microservices, azure-service-fabric

The documentation for updating x509 certificates in Service Fabric is unclear to me with regards to non-Azure (On-Prem) installations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-upgrade-windows-server

I have followed these steps, but they have not worked.

1. Updated the cluster setup json template so that the thumbprint of the original certificate is now "ThumbprintSecondary".
2. Added the new certificate thumbprint under "Thumbprint". e.g.

   "security": {
        "metadata": "The Credential type X509 indicates this is cluster is 
         secured using X509 Certificates. The thumbprint format is - d5 ec 42 3b 79 cb e5 07 fd 83 59 3c 56 b9 d5 31 24 25 42 64.",
           "ClusterCredentialType": "X509",
           "ServerCredentialType": "X509",
           "CertificateInformation": {
               "ClusterCertificate": {
                   "Thumbprint": "New Thumbprint",
                   "ThumbprintSecondary": "Old Thumbprint",
                   "X509StoreName": "My"
           },
           "ServerCertificate": {
           "Thumbprint": "New Thumbprint",
           "ThumbprintSecondary": "Old Thumbprint",
           "X509StoreName": "My"
       },
3. Install the new certificate pfx and update the ACL for "NETWORK SERVICE"
4. Run Start-ServiceFabricClusterConfigurationUpgrade -ClusterConfigPath "Path to json Configuration File"

Comment: "Not worked" - what errors do you get?

Comment: I've updated the SDK and it seems to work for me now. I'll close this question off

Answer (score 2):

for your question, no there is no out of the box way to update Certificate for Service Fabric on-premise cluster.
I opened a ticket with Microsoft for this issue: 117011115158708 and they replied it will be fixed on version 5.5
this version is out now and the problem still not fixed, they should get back to me with an answer about this issue, i will try to keep this post updated.

Comment: According to the last comment on the original question, it seems to work with the latest SDK

Comment: @Alex how do you do it?

Comment: @SturmUndDrang Maybe you can explain, your comment mentions "seems to work for me now"

Answer (score 0):

Certificate update would be a cluster configuration change. The following method has worked for me for cluster configuration changes.

- Install the new cert on all nodes as you've already done.
- Run `Get-ServiceFabricRegisteredClusterConfigVersion`. The highest number
  listed will most likely be the cluster config version you are on.
- Run `Get-ServiceFabricClusterManifest | Out-File C:\ClusterManifest.xml`
- Edit the `ClusterManifest.xml` file and make the following changes:

  - Upgrade the Version attribute on the root ClusterManifest XML tag
    (e.g. if it is 1, go to 2)
  - Update the thumbprints under the Certificates section
- Use `Copy-ServiceFabricClusterPackage` with `-Config` option (I have not included the full syntax but you can look that up as it is quite detailed) and specify the modified ClusterManifest.xml file.
- Run `Get-ServiceFabricRegisteredClusterConfigVersion`. The version you just
  uploaded will now be the highest version (e.g. 2 in this example).
- Run `Start-ServiceFabricClusterUpgrade -Config -ClusterManifestVersion`
  *new-version* (2 in this example; again I have left out other
  parameters for simplicity).